# javascript regexp - split string at last token

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to provide autocomplete for an expression input in java script.

These are the relevant tokens

```
+ - * / [ ] [[ ]] ( ) ! != == . .* .^ ./ < > <= >= : ,
```

I'm trying to split a string at the occurrence of the last token into lhs,rhs and token

For example

```
sum(            ->  `lhs=sum, token=(, rhs=`

sum(x           ->  `lhs=sum, token=(, rhs=x`

sum(x)          ->  `lhs=sum(x, token=), rhs=`

sum(x) + sum(y  ->  `lhs=sum(x) + sum token=(, rhs=y`

[[1,2]],[[      ->  `lhs=[[1,2]], token=[[, rhs=`

[[1,2]],[ [     ->  `lhs=[[1,2]], token=[ [, rhs=`

[[1,2]],[[i     ->  `lhs=[[1,2]], token=[[, rhs=i`

[[1,2]],[[i:    ->  `lhs=[[1,2]],[[i token=:, rhs=`

1 + 2 / A[1     ->  `lhs=1 + 2 / A, token=[, rhs=1`
```

I'm currently doing `Math.max(term.lastIndexOf(","),term.lastIndexOf("(") ... )` which is inefficient and does not provide the  token when it's more then one latter long. Plus, if some token has a white space in it (which is legal - for example `[ [`) it's not catching it.

I know regex experts have a soft spot for parsers so i'll appreciate some help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write expressions for each token and alternate them in a capturing group. Escape what's needed. Putting the longest ones first.

Then you could either match or split through the string. For example:

```
var re = /(\+|-|\*|\/|\[\[|\]\]|\[|\]|\(|\)|!=|!|==|\.\*|\.^|\.|\.\/|<=|>=|<|>|\:|\,)/;
var m = str.split(re);
if(m){
    var rhs = m.pop();
    var token = m.pop();
    var lhs = m.join("");
}
```

If you want to allow optional spaces between `[[` change the `\[\[` expression accordingly (depending on what you mean by spaces). For example `\[\s*\[`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - try `X[[1` it produces lhs=X[,token=[,rhs=1 it should produce lhs=X,token=[[,rhs=1. I see that you've put the double digit token first in the regex though it still capture the single digit token- is there any way of making it greedy ?

Comment: Hey, reducing this to the bare minimum (no white space yet) `"X[[1".match(/(.*)(\[\[|\[)(.*)/)` produces `["X[[1", "X[", "[", "1"]` which is not greedy. expected result is `[ X, [[ , 1 ]`.

Comment: @haki, right. That's because `.*` *is* greedy. Updated the answer.